# TypeError: Not enough arguments with window.postMessage on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios

```js
window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
    type: 'loggedIn',
    userToken: token,
}));
```

My problem is from the above code.
It gives me `TypeError: Not enough arguments` on ios devices.
Please help me if you experienced this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supplying both required arguments. From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage):

> ```
>  targetWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
> ```

Note that `targetOrigin` is not optional. Specify the target origin of the message, e.g.:

```
window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
    type: 'loggedIn',
    userToken: token,
}), window.origin);
```

Comment: it's working on other system though. (Ubuntu, Windows). I will try your solution though.

Comment: @RobertB.  Sometimes implementations allow things that are technically invalid. As far as I can tell from [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#dom-window-postmessage), MDN is correct that it's required.